# Flood Plain Mapping using HEC-GeoRAS and ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, flood, hec-georas

How can I get complete bounding polygon of XS CutLines for flood plain mapping (Flood Inundation Mapping) using HEC-GeoRAS and ArcMap 10.3?

When I tried to perform this task, the bounding polygon formed was in an unexpected manner.

[image]

I want to get the bounding polygon without the gap that is visible around the river junction.

Answer (score 1):

Inundation mapping at junctions isn't perfect within HEC-RAS. I'd suggest manually editing the output based on your judgement.